# Django file based email backend

Tags: python, django

It's probably something very obvious, but I can't seem to figure it out.

This snippet is from Django's file based email backend (django.core.mail.backends.filebased.py)

```
    def write_message(self, message):
        self.stream.write(message.message().as_bytes() + b"\n")
```

My question is. How can I find out what class is **message** an object of?

**Context for why:**
My code sends emails along various execution paths. I want to leverage Django's filebased backend, instead of firing live emails during debugging and unit testing (*or creating my own file based system*). The relevant code has a MIMEMultipart object currently (*with utf-8 coded text*) that works fine for production. I need to be able to convert that into an object that can be printed legibly by the above snippet.

PS: I come from a C++ background where this would've been an easy question to answer.

Comment: You can use `type(message)` or `message.__class__`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use python's builtin type function.

```
type(obj)
```

Or if you want to check if it is an instance of a specific object use isinstance function.

```
if isinstance(obj, Obj_Class):
   # do something
```